# Convergence of Riemann Zeta Series for Re(s) = 1

Tags: complex-analysis

This question has been asked before but unfortunately not correctly answered yet. My question is if the Riemann Zeta Series is convergent for $\Re(s) = 1$ except for $s =1$ (I am not talking about Riemann Zeta function which would be the analytical continuation of this series). On one side, I see that everywhere in the literature the restriction of $\Re(s) > 1$ is being made, on the other side, I just cannot understand how an analytical continuation can take place if the series in divergent for $\Re(s) = 1$. That way the plane is divided into two disconnected regions.

Comment: Meditate on the simple case $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0}{e^{-nz}}$ which converges normally when $\Re z >0$, obviously doesn't converge when $\Re z \le 0$ (terms do not go to zero) but it also represents $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}$ which is analytic in the whole plane except at integral multiples of $2 \pi i$

Comment: Another example is $\frac{1}{1-z}$ whose Maclaurin series converges in $|z|<1$ and diverges in $|z| \ge 1$.  Nevertheless, it extends analytically to the plane except $1$.

Comment: Many thanks to Conrad and GEdgar. I myself also considered the example that GEdgar gave. But my question was also about the analytical continuation. Obviously the 1/(1-z) is defined outside the circle, but if it weren't how would it be possible to extend a function analytically from the inside the unit circle to the outside of it if it is undefined on the unit circle? Is there an example of a power series that is convergent inside the circle, divergent on the circle and for which there exists no analytical continuation to the outside of the circle?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).

Comment: Thanks metamorphy :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}-\frac{(N+1)^{1-s}-1}{1-s}= \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}-\int_1^{N+1} x^{-s}dx$$ $$ = \sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1} (n^{-s}-x^{-s})dx=\sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x st^{-s-1}dtdx$$
As $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x st^{-s-1}dtdx$ converges for $\Re(s) > 0$ and $\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{(N+1)^{1-s}-1}{1-s}$ converges iff $\Re(s) > 1$,

> Then $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}$ converges iff $\Re(s) > 1$.